# Images not loading on webpage, and links to other media give 404 Not Found

Tags: images, permalinks, media, 404-error

Had some recent problems where to start with only homepage text was visible, all other pages/links gave 404 Not Found.

Now managed to get pages to function but all images fail to load, plus links to other media give "Sorry, this page doesn't exist. Please check the URL or go back a page. 404 Error. Page Not Found"

Media files are all there in wp-content/uploads so something is preventing site 'seeing' them, suspect the same issue is causing the problem with the images *and* the media files.

Also RSS feed not working but as this too depends on a link maybe is part of the same problem?

Have deactivated plugins in case there was a conflict but this does not help.

NB I'm an admin not developer, ie a real novice, can get into files via cPanel, can edit text in files given instruction but not much more.....

Comment: in my case, a plugin named as "WebP Express" create a htaccess file in uploads folder that restrict my access to some images.
try rename or remove it and see if the problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues when moving WP sites in the past. I'm guessing you have gone to `settings > permalinks` and clicked save to get your interior page links working? For image links, if you go to `settings > media` you should see only your thumbnail sizes. If you see a textbook that has a file path inside it, try editing that textbook to just read /wp-content/uploads/ and click save. That will tell WordPress where you are storing images (it has basically got itself confused from a previous server configuration). Your images should return... Fingers crossed!

Comment: sorry, textbox auto corrected to textbook...

Comment: Thanks - done that with no effect. Settings > media does just only show thumbnail sizes. NB I didn't move the site, the problem developed without any input from me!

Comment: Interesting, has anything changed in the hosting environment? PHP version for example, what are you on now? Is Mod_Rewrite enabled? Could you possibly paste in the contents of your site htaccess file and if possible give the URL??

Comment: System PHP is 7.3, Domain PHP is 5.6 (which may be an issue)

Comment: URL is woodlandcrofts.org

Comment: htaccess file follows

Comment: # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# eig_rock_conv
# Set the "ea-php54" package as the default "PHP" programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php54 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress

Comment: Finally, don't know what Mod_Rewrite is nor where to find it......

Comment: Thanks for sending over the URL. All of the images on the page look to be referencing perhaps a dev URL (http://woodlandcrofts.org.cp-27.webhostbox.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Oak-skidding.jpg). It looks like you just need to do a search and replace in the Db. I'd recommend using a plugin called ```Velvet Blues``` and run that to replace ```http://woodlandcrofts.org.cp-27.webhostbox.net``` with ```http://woodlandcrofts.org``` - Take care when doing this that the ends of your domains match. If one ends in /, so must the other, otherwise you'll end up with a bigger problem!

Comment: Thanks - very interesting. Have to say the 'webhostbox.net' bit is something that I've seen ever since the site was set up (eg in page URLs) however didn't previously cause a problem. Incidentally, http://woodlandcrofts.org.cp-27.webhostbox.net appears in the wp-options db in a row whose option_name

Comment: is 'home'. Tried changing that just to woodlandcrofts.org as an experiment but made no difference.

Comment: Incidentally, Velvet Blues says not marked as compatible with my version of Wordpress (which is an early one). Need to do an update but need to fix site first....

Comment: is there a way to manually change a single reference only, to check this fixes the problem? Then I'd have confidence to do a find & replace for all of them, assuming there's another plugin compatible with my version of WP.

Comment: If you were to edit the homepage content and adjust the URL on your image there from ```http://woodlandcrofts.org.cp-27.webhostbox.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Oak-skidding.jpg``` to ```http://woodlandcrofts.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Oak-skidding.jpg```, then you'll see that the image will load in. I would suggest changing the setting in the options to the live domain. I'd imagine wherever this was developed, the development site has just been turned off, which is why the issue now shows. If you'd like, feel free to call on +44 1452 221 222

Comment: Brilliant!!! You're an absolute star, thank you *so* much for this. I've started to work through the pages changing the links & TBH happy to do this manually rather than with a plugin as it's not a huge site and it allows me to check all links are working (already found a broken one this way). Thanks again!